# unfortunately, connection has stopped

Tags: android, android-volley, genymotion

I am trying to make a simple android app to connect to localhost database and retrieve data from the same.

I use volley library and my php scripts are working fine. I am using Genymotion emulator. Everytime I launch the application, I get the following error message:"unfortunately, connection has stopped ".

Is it something related to the emulator?

My main activity is:

```
      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText editTextId;
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;

private ProgressDialog loading;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextId = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    buttonGet = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    textViewResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewresult);

    buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void getData(){
    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    if(id.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter an ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait....","Fetching...",false,false);
    String url = Config.DATA_URL+id;

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,new Response.Listener<String>(){

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response){
            loading.dismiss();
            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){
    String name="";
    String address="";
    String director="";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
        name = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        address = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        director = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_DIRECTOR);
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText("Name:\t"+name+"Address:\t"+address+"Director:\t"+director);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    getData();
}
```

}

The config file:

```
    public class Config {
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/getDatanew.php?id=";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_DIRECTOR = "director";
public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
```

}

The dataConnect.php file:

```
    <?php


$con = new mysqli("localhost","root","","college") or die ('Unable to Connect');
if ($con->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

The getData.php file

```
    <?php

//if($_SERVER['REQUESTED_METHOD']=='GET'){
    if($_GET['id']){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if($id)
         //echo 'hello '.$id;


    require_once('dbConnectnew.php');

    //echo $con;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM college WHERE id='".$id."'";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    //if(!$r){
    //printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
```

//  exit();
//}

```
    $res = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $result = array();

    array_push($result,array(
    "name"=>$res['name'],
    "address"=>$res['address'],
    "director"=>$res['director']
    )
    );

    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
}else echo 'no if';
?>
```

Comment: post your code what you have done...!!

Comment: make it more brief

Comment: code has been included

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 127.0.0.1, try putting in the Ip Address of your WiFi or LAN. You can get it by running the ipconfig in cmd.